# Getting "Class not found in" on production but not on local or dev server

Tags: php, wordpress, class, namespaces, autoload

### UPDATE 1:

After finding out the issue lies with the order in which the plugins are loaded, I am left with the question why the plugin load order changed between 2 dev servers and even between the local development environment and the new dev server.

My issue might be solved because of using the plugin not as normal but as a "Must-use plugin", this does keep me wondering how the load order changed suddenly.

If you have any info on this that would be of big help.
I will still be searching answers on this issue and update this page when I have more info.

### Original Question:

For the past 3 days I have been banging my head against the wall harder and harder.
I am missing something but I don't know what.

Things to know before we continue.

At the company I work for we have a few servers for live websites and a single dev server.
As this server setup was not working for us anymore and was born out of panic we need to build it up from the scratch.

We did just that and now have 1 development machine and 2 live servers.
All servers run the same version of software.

- Ubuntu 20.04 lts
- Apache 7.4.12
- php 7.4

We use bitbucket to store our source code and use Jenkins to deploy to the dev and live servers.

We are using namespaces with the classes and I don't use composer.

After fully testing if the 1 of our websites would keep working while being deployed to the old dev-server I moved on to setting everything up for the new development server.

**note: the old webserver was on PHP 7.2 and apache 2.4.35**

After deploying the site to the new development server it seems that for some reason I always get this message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: `Class 'Utils\Notifications' not found in...`

The weird thing here is that, even though it is not working on the server, it is working perfectly find on the old dev server and the local development machine.
To be clear, the local development machine uses the same versions of apache and php together with the same modules and extensions.

The website is a Wordpress site.
The issue is within a plugin that I created that auto loads all the classes within a set folder.
I have tried debugging the code locally, even though it works there, and can't find anything weird. All is working well without issues.

The only thing I found weird was that after placing a `die();` command at the start of the plugin that autoloads the classes it doesn't die.
It still crashes on the same error.

I know this would suggest that the code is run in a wrong order.
Weirdly enough it still works locally and on the current live website and development server.

My question could probably be this.

- what am I missing here?
- would it be possible that Wordpress loads plugins in different random orders
- what kind of tests could I still perform.

### Things I already tried

- Checked for typo's
- checked if capital letters were missing
- checked if the functions in question get the correct values in parameters (local debugging)
- tried changing the order of loading for wordpress plugins using the `add_action('plugins_loaded', [function name], 10)` (and 11 on the plugin that keeps crashing)
- compared all php modules with the current dev server and local php development server (using laragon)
- removed the autoloader and used includes as I thought maybe the autoloader ran later (issue stayed)

### Code

Below is the autoload function I use.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $className = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    if(file_exists(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/classes/' . $className . '.php')){
        include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/classes/' . $className . '.php';
    }
});
```

This is the class that should be autoloaded

```
namespace Utils;
...
...
class NotificationCore {
...
...
class Notifications extends NotificationCore {
..
```

this is the code giving the error:

```
<?php 

   use Utils\Notifications;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   if (Notifications::isThereOutage()) {
       notificationScript();
   }
```

I have tried not using the `use` part and just use `Utils\Notifications` but without any luck.
Also tried it with a pre-backslash `\Utils\Notifications` but this makes no change at all.

I am at a complete loss here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after a desperate attempt to get things working again.
Or at least to find out if it was the server or Wordpress I put the plugin that was Autoloading into the mu-plugin directory.
Even though this was never a way we wanted to use, after some reconsiderations, me and a colleague agreed that this might even be a better choice.

the plugin that wasn't found is very important to the website as it would break if the plugin was not active. So we decided to use it as mu-plugin.

This doesn't solve the issue though.
For some reason the order in which plugins are loaded completely changes between servers.
This needs some more research on its own.

I am not going to mark this question as the answer to the question.
Instead I am going to edit the question with where maybe people can answer how Wordpress decides what plugins to load and when.